# Generate regex only between two number but find all number include 1 to 10

Tags: regex

I want to generate regex only between 1 to 10. I use this

```
(10|[1-9])
```

Notepad++ finds all the numbers that start 1 to 10, but I want to find only 1 to 10 numbers not all numbers that include part of 1 to 10.

Comment: Just so you know, we encourage posters to make an attempt first, and to present it in their question. Some times when people make an attempt for the purposes of asking a well-researched question, they solve the problem themselves, so it is well worth a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use word boundaries since it helps the regex engine to do an exact match.

```
\b(10|[1-9])\b
```

`\b` called word boundary which matches between a word character and a non-word character, vice-versa.